# Read and Write Socket-SerialPort use expensive CPU

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def threadSocket(Socket, port):
    '''
    Thread encargado de sotener comunicacion entre Socket cliente y
    el puerto serial asignado
    Mientras se mantenga activo el thread de recepcion se intentara leer del
    puerto serial y enviarlo al socket cliente
    Se asume que socket y port son objetos vaidos validos
    '''
    #Intenta abrir el puerto serial
    try:
        COM = serial.Serial(port-1)
    except:
        #Si esta en uso no se encuentra disponible, muestra error
        print 'Error: Puerto COM'+str(port)+' no disponible'
    else:
        #Al conectarse se crea el thread de recepcion
        print 'Conectado a puerto COM'+str(port)
        rxThread = threading.Thread(target=rxThreadDef,args=(Socket,COM))
        rxThread.start()
        dato = ''
        #Mientras el thread este activo
        while rxThread.isAlive():
            try:
                #Lee del puerto serial y envia a Socket cliente
                dato += COM.read()
                if parserCOMToSocket(dato):
                    Socket.send(dato)
                    dato=''
            except:
                break
        print "Puerto cerrado!"
        #Cierra puerto Serial
        COM.close()
    #Cierra Socket
    Socket.close()
    #print "Hilo terminado"
def rxThreadDef(Socket,COM):
    '''
    Thread (Hilo) encargado de recibir la informacion del Cliente
    y enviarla por medio del puerto serial
    Si se genera algun error se rompe el ciclo y termina el thread
    '''
    dato = ''
    while 1:
        try:
            d = Socket.recv(1024)
        except:
            break
        if d:
            dato += d
            if parserSocketToCOM(dato):
                COM.write(dato)
                print dato
                dato = ''
        else:
            break

def parserSocketToCOM(dato):
    return True

def parserCOMToSocket(dato):
    return True
```

Hi, I try to implement a bridge between a serial port and a AIR application using sockets in Python 2.7

When the ***rxThread*** die, the ***socketThread*** will be able to close the socket and the serial Port because the client socket is die. But the script need to wait for a read from the serial port before close all.

If I try with a `timeout=0`, the CPU usage grow to 100%. If I try with a `timeout=None` but use `COM.isWaiting()`, I will get the same problem (100% of CPU)

How can I know if a socket is closed in other way?

Comment: Do I understand well if I think that you wish to read from two sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read from two sources, you can do it happily with [`select()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select). You won't need threads in that case. `select` blocks until one or more of the resources is available, and then returns the set of resources available, so you can react on each. Note that `select` works with [file descriptors](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.fileno) and you may need to put it in [nonblocking mode](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.nonblocking).